# Spotify not playing local files

Tags: wine, mp3, spotify

Spotify when ran using wine will not play local files (mp3's, wma's). When i open the Containing folder the files are present but when selected from the wine explorer it gives the error message: "there is no windows program configured to open this type of file"

Comment: Why use wine when there is a native app? https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/

Answer (score 0):

As @Matteo noted in the comments, there is a [native Linux binary](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/) which works much better than the (unsupported) Wine version. Local files work just fine with this client.